# How can i add days to time stamp

Tags: php, time

How can i add days to time stamp and echo the time.
I tried and able to add days to it but when  echo it shows a no's.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('+7 days', $row['sdate']);
```

Is this code is correct.

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like

```
$date = strtotime($row['sdate']);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
```

OR you can also try like

```
$date = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($row['sdate']) );
echo date('Y-m-d',$date);
```

Comment: thnx..but how can i echo the new date now.

Comment: how can i convert $date to timestamp if i have to add some days in timestamp and store the new timestamp back to database..cause i think using strtotime will change its datatype(it will no longer remain timestamp..will it?) so what to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime function wants unix timestamp, so you need to convert your time  (that i expect is normal datetime)?

```
strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($row['sdate']) );
```

Then if you want to format it to datetime again you do like this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($row['sdate']) );
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

You can read more about strtotime and date on php's manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php